# Exception in SaveChanges() method (Entity.Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

There is class `User`

```
namespace TaskManager.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        private const int NAME_LENGTH = 200;
        private const int EMAIL_LENGTH = 100;
        private const int PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 5;
        private const int PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 20;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(NAME_LENGTH)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(EMAIL_LENGTH)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(UserType.User)]
        public UserType Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public enum UserType
    {
        Admin = 0,
        User = 1
    }
}
```

and I try to create custom user registration using [SimpleCrypto](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleCrypto/).
Here is my method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Registration()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsUserExist(user.Email))
        {

            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

            var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

            var newUser = _db.Users.Create();

            newUser.Name = user.Name;
            newUser.Email = user.Email;
            newUser.Type = UserType.User.ToString();

            newUser.Password = encrpPass;
            newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

            _db.Users.Add(newUser);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User already exists");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is incorrect");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

If I use this table schema, registration works correctly 
[image]

but if I try to set `Id` as `Primary Key` and set `Identity == true` and `Identity Increment = 1`

[image]

I got an Exception in `_db.SaveChanges();` method.
What do I do wrong? How to fix it?

**Exception**

System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = Id ]

I tried to change model

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

but I got the same exception.

Comment: what exception did you get?

Comment: I update my question, at the end.

Comment: Maybe I should not use EDMX  at all and use some other way?

Comment: No, you just need to update your EDMX (Update model from Database). The attributes you show are for Code First.

Comment: Could  you explain me how to do that, please?

Comment: [How to: Update an .edmx File when the Database Changes (Entity Data Model Tools)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I've already found out this tutorial. But when I try to Update Model from Database, I can't choose any option http://i.imgur.com/8mBu1pD.png because all checkboxes are unactive.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the Refresh tab?

Comment: @CodeCaster, oh, so I just needed to choose 'Finish' option. Now it works. Thanks a lot for help.